# Increasing the style spline resolution

Tags: solidworks

I have a style spline that when extruded have sharp coroners inside of a smooth curve

Is there a way to increase its resolution?

- Note that its not solidworks graphics setting, it does in fact actually 3d print like shown in the picture

[image]

When I try to split with an offset line, this happens
[image]

There is a thin wall that is cut as well, which shows that there is something going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your STL export settings - the spline *is* perfectly smooth mathematically, and there are separate settings for the SW graphic window and STL export which both approximate the curve as a series of straight lines.

http://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/hidd_stl.htm?verRedirect=1

Comment: Thanks! I added a photo of what happens if i split it be an offset line, seems like a symptom 
Any thoughts on this?